# PHP code working on xampp but it does not work on raspberry pi

Tags: php, ajax, apache, paypal, raspberry-pi3

I have built a code to call PayPal REST API to pay by credit card. I have it nicely works on Xampp but it does not work on raspberry pi. It's return

> **Internal server error 500**

when I enable the debug to finger out what is the actual error I get

> **Class 'PayPal\Api\fundingInstrument' not found in**

No idea why I am getting this error since it's working on Xampp

please Help?

Comment: can be the php version. What do you have in xampp and what do you have in raspberry?

Comment: How are you loading the PayPal library?

Comment: If you are using composer do composer dump-autoload

Comment: bytheway is autoloader fault... are you using composer for loading classes?

Comment: Xampp V: 5.6.24

on ras : 5.6.30

Comment: Yes I am using composer @GabrieleCarbonai

Comment: How I do composer dump-autoad? @PetyoTsonev

Answer (score 0):

If you are using composer there are some methods.

1. Install composer in rasp in the project folder then do `php composer.phar dump-autoload`
2. In xampp do `php composer.phar dump-autoload` then upload the project again to rasp.

If you are not using composer just do `require_once("File to require")`

Comment: I am sorry, but I didn't get it. can you explain that in more details.
@Petyo Tsonev 

Thanks

Comment: First of all do you have composer installed on the rasp ?

Comment: Okay, in the project folder in your PC do php composer.phar (OR composer depends on your setup) dump-autoload. After that copy the project to device again